# When trying to run flutter application there is a Error in build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle

In my first time, I have generated `key.properties` file and add to `build.gradle` file. Then I tried to `flutter run` It's Not working.
[image]

My `build.gradle` file.

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.calculator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: `localProperties` is undefined

Comment: I make it @spartygw. Bur, it still does not work. In Command-line shows.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Cannot parse project property android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs='false.' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

`localProperties` is undefined. Try this:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
```

Comment: I add those codes. but It still not working. In command Line show this Error
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Cannot parse project property android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs='false.' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: Do you have that in gradle.properties? It should not have quotes around `false`

Comment: I make a flutter app and trying to upload it to google playstore then I got this problem.

Comment: I will try those cases and search all the stack overflow but I can't solve that problem

Comment: Which file has `android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs='false'` in it? You need to find that file and fix that.